# When/Why should I use Git Bash, Command Prompt, Powershell?

Tags: git, powershell

I've never had much experience with the Command Prompt/PowerShell (my only use is to occasionally ping google for connection speed when travelling) and I'm trying to understand its usefulness. I've seen that Powershell is a popular tool for developers from StackOverflow's yearly survey, but I don't know/understand why people use it:

[image: Powershell is ranked 6th in terms of popularity for programming, scripting, and markup languages]

I use Git Bash for working with Github and from what I've read online it can do most of what the Command Prompt does.

I also know that PowerShell ISE is used for scripting; my current understanding is that it's an overcharged version of PowerShell because easier at creating scripts. But couldn't I simply just use a code editor like VS Code or Sublime or Atom?

From what I've read, the Command Prompt is a worse version of PowerShell, but I really don't know much about it.

So to summarize, I'm currently not using the Command Prompt or PowerShell much at all, and I use Git Bash only for Github.

Can someone help me with determining why or why not -as a web developer- PowerShell or the Command Prompt should be used? Should I simply stick with Git Bash?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinion based and likely to be closed, and this is too long for a comment.

Anyway, I guess it would depend on when and how you developed your computing experience.  I started in the early 80s, so my first Windows experience (Win3.11) it was actually getting in my way.  On my minimal hardware (386sx w/ 4mb ram, 14.4 modem) it didn't let me do any of the cool "this is why you want windows" stuff at a speed worth doing it.  Win95 and a new top of the line computer helped, but when I got onto Linux in '97 I immediately gravitated back to the command line, and had the best of both worlds.

While I worked in a Windows enterprise and supported Windows (and Mac) users, on my desktop and laptops both home and work I have used nothing but Linux since 1999 until January of this year, when I took a new position as a developer.  And I *really* miss things like recursive `grep`ping, `find`ing files and performing operations on them, `tail`ing log files, quickly backing up with a `tar` command, symlinking files to where I need a second copy, etc.

In short, for web dev use (LAMP or MEAN, etc) I'd look at what `grep`,`find`,`head`,`tail`,`sed`, and `ln` can do for you (and except for `ln` there are Windows builds out there or you maybe could use the Linux subsystem in Win10, or if you are on a Mac just use the `Terminal` app).

Fortunately my complaints and whining have been heard and apparently I get to beta test a Linux dev workstation set up starting in about a month :)

Finally, remember than even for a sysadmin to automate something, he or she will need to program.  This is why you see a large percentage of users liking/using/wanting a good shell interpreter that is "integrated" to the way the system it runs on works.  Could you imaging having to schedule a job that is only doable via GUI interaction, but needs to run at 3am? What do you do - record mouse clicks, etc. and hope the screen resolution, etc don't change?

Comment: Great, thank you for your response. I'm new to SE so I wasn't sure if I was going to get one. Quick clarification question: You haven't used much of Window's programs (Command Prompt & Powershell) since the 90s? If you have since, can I get your opinion on it? Thank you

Comment: @JustinArenson - nope. Can't even access cmd on the work computers (I can in one of the labs I teach in, but I can boot Linux off the network there too).  As long as you stay away from opinion based answers, you'll be at least OK on the SE sites - the goal is more towards (somewhat)  definitive answers to well asked and thought out questions rather than discussions and what-abouts.  I'd recommend checking out superuser.com and read to see what utilities people are using for things in the Windows world.